# Sorting by name in django

Tags: python, django

I am using this code

```
episodes=Episode.objects.filter().order_by('name')
```

I am getting results as

```
episode 1
episode 10
episode 11
episode 12
episode 2
```

instead 
I want the result as

```
episode 1 episode 2 episode 10 episode 11
```

Comment: Do you have other field that represent the episode number? name is charfield, of course it is sorted by alpha order. If your don't, the design of the schema is wrong,you will have more troubles later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably best to store episode number as an int field and sort by that.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    episode_num = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'episode {}'.format(self.episode_num)

Episode.objects.order_by('episode_num')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database schema structure is wrong.

Django ORM queries are finally translated to SQL. You can't do such kind of order by directly in any db columns.

At least, you should split the series name with episode number.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    num = models.IntegerField()

Episode.objects.order_by('name', 'num')
```

Episodes will be ordered by their series name in alpha order then by episode number in numeric order.

In my experience, even the structure above is not good enough in most cases. episode names are actually series name, it should be separated to another table. I'll create models like this:

```
class Series(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class Episode(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey('Series')
    num = models.IntegerField()
```

Answer (score 0):

If episode name is having space as separator between name of episode and number of episode then you can follow below process.
Your design of the schema is wrong.
But still if you want to continue with it i will tell you the way . as per coding, performance basis that may not good solution but still it will fulfill your requirement.
Please see below code .

```
####List of episodes  
episodes = [str(a[0]) for a in Episode.objects.filter().values_list('name')]
#sorting of episoded
sorted_episodes = sorted(episodes, key=lambda x:x.split('  ')[-1] in episodes)
print sorted_episodes
```